# The below code generates the 32x32 hadamard matrix.But how do i write it recursively?

Tags: c

This code is taking the spreading factor as input and giving the output as hadamard matrix.For example if spreading factor is 4 the hadamard matrix will be 4x4. Can anyone one tell me how do i write it recursively.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m = 2, i, j, spread_fact;
    int a[128][128], b[128][128];

    printf("enter the initial matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("the entered matrix is\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("enter the spreading factor\n");
    scanf("%d", &spread_fact);
    while (m < spread_fact) {
        m = 2 * m;
        printf("m value is:%d\n", m);
        for (i = 0; i < m / 2; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m / 2; j++) {
                b[i][j] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < m / 2; i++) {
            for (j = m / 2; j < m; j++) {
                b[i][j] = a[i][j - m / 2];
            }
        }
        for (i = m / 2; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m / 2; j++) {
                b[i][j] = a[i - m / 2][j];
            }
        }
        for (i = m / 2; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = m / 2; j < m; j++) {
                b[i][j] = -a[i - m / 2][j - m / 2];
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                a[i][j] = b[i][j];
                printf("the matrix is %d\n", a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("the matrix is:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? How did that work? Or how *didn't* that work? What problems do you have with your attempt? Oh, and *please* learn to indent your code "properly", so it becomes readable.

Comment: 1. Code Indention, that stuff is almost unreadable by humans. 
2. Post some example you have tried yourself

Answer (score 1):

First, let's simplify your algorithm and wrap it into a function:

```
void mhadam(int a[MAX][MAX], int m, int M)
{
    int i, j;

    while (m < M) {
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                a[i + m][j] = a[i][j];
                a[i][j + m] = a[i][j];
                a[i + m][j + m] = -a[i][j];
            }
        }
        m = 2 * m;
    }
}
```

The main feature here is the `while` loop. Instead of traversing this loop multiple times, you can call this function recursively if your spread factor `M` hasn't been reached:

```
void mhadam_rec(int a[MAX][MAX], int m, int M)
{
    int i, j;

    if (m < M) {
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                a[i + m][j] = a[i][j];
                a[i][j + m] = a[i][j];
                a[i + m][j + m] = -a[i][j];
            }
        }
        mhadam_rec(a, 2*m, M);
    }
}
```

Here, the loop and recursive functions are very similar. In my opinion, a recursive approach doesn't buy you anything here. In fact, such recursions where the recursive call is the last statement in the function, are called tail recursions and one of their properties is that they can be optimised into a loop.

**Edit**: For completeness's sake, here is a small program that calculated the 16×16 Hadamard matrix:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 128

void mprint(int a[MAX][MAX], int m)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void mhadam_rec(int a[MAX][MAX], int m, int M)
{
    int i, j;

    if (m < M) {
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                a[i + m][j] = a[i][j];
                a[i][j + m] = a[i][j];
                a[i + m][j + m] = -a[i][j];
            }
        }
        mhadam_rec(a, 2*m, M);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[MAX][MAX];
    int m = 1;
    int M = 16;

    a[0][0] = 1;

    mhadam_rec(a, m, M);
    mprint(a, M);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this function and but its not entering the function only.Can u please add that function in my program and send the code??

Comment: What doesn't work? Just set up a small matrix, say for `m == 2` like you do in your code and then call `mhadam(a, m, spread_factor)` or `mhadam_rec(a, m, spread_factor)`. The code above doen't print anything, you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: ya I did that one.But its printing only till m value.Its not entering the function when it is called

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. When you call a function, the function is entered. Note that the new dimension of the matrix is `spread_factor`, not `m`. The function doesn't update `m`.